# Magento Test Automation Framework and Community Edition

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, testing, taf

Over the last weekend I made the effort to experiment with [Magento's Test Automation Framework](https://github.com/magento/taf) (TAF), after a fashion, I got it up and running. However many/most of the bundled core tests do not pass for me, perhaps as many as 70% fail or are skipped.

I tested TAF's master branch from git against a clean install of 1.7.0.2 community, with selenium server 2.31.0, using the firefox profile and with PHP 5.4.

What sort of test pass rate should we expect with TAF and Community Edition, and if you get a higher pass rate what combination of PHP, Selenium and Browser type are you using?

Comment: 1.x is supposed to work on PHP 5.2, I believe taf tests too.

Comment: Ben got a lot of fails this weekend too when he ran it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run them with PHP 5.4 and the 1.8 pre-release from github and I think most of them run. You need to have a clean database, with sample data you have many errors.

https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013

And you have to set the admin-url and the admin user/password in the `config.yml` file

And last but not least you have ti copy the `.htaccess.sample` to `.htaccess`, if not, all the admin tests fail and all depending tests are skipped.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I am still having problems with my test suite but the .htaccess tip reduced quite a few, and now I've zeroed it down to paypal setup. Glad to know that the tests *do* mostly pass. Cheers!

Comment: Also important. TAF has A LOT of issues with locale settings (both Magento and system-wide) Magento must be set to default locale (en_US) because a lot of tests depend on english titles or other strings. I am also experiencing failed tests due to date format in fixture data. So far I think this is a system locale issue, but i am looking further into it on my spare time